# How are dependencies handled in c9's Architect?

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm looking at [c9's Architect](https://github.com/c9/architect) for building a modular node.js app, but I can't seem to find any info about handling dependencies.

For example, say I write a plugin that uses something like `lodash`. Do I include the dependency in my root `package.json`, or do I add it to my plugin's `package.json`? If it's the latter, I suspect I'll need to run `npm install` in the plugin folder, but going in to every plugin directory and doing that could be tedious. Is this expected behaviour and is there a better way of managing dependencies when using Architect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A month on, I've had a good chance to play with Architect, so I can answer my own questions.

Yes, dependencies are handled by the package.json in your plugin's folder, so `npm install --save` them in your plugin's directory

As for running `npm install` on all the folders, I wrote a gulp task to automate the process. I hammered this out in a few minutes so there's room for improvement, but:

```
var gulp = require("gulp")
var dir = require("node-dir")

gulp.task("install-plugins", function(callback) {
  console.log("Installing dependencies for plugins")
  dir.paths(__dirname + "/plugins", function(err, paths) {
    try {
      paths.dirs.forEach(function(item) {
        if (item.indexOf("node_modules") > -1 || item.indexOf("bower_components") > -1) {
          return
        }
        console.log("Running 'npm install' in " + item)
        cp.execSync("npm install", {
          cwd: item
        })
      })
    } catch (ex) {
      console.log("Failed to run 'npm install'. Error was: " + ex)
    }
  })
  callback()
})
```